# Cororna SDK - How to make objects interact when hitting each other

Tags: coronasdk

I am kinda new to Corona, I need to make lets say a ball object when it hits a user-controlled object the user controlled object will (do something), the problem is i cant define that the 2 objects will hit each other, Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Can you show some code you have done so far?

Comment: Look into collision events in Corona.  https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/api/event/collision/index.html